# TypeOrm ManyToMany JoinTable data automatically dropped during initialization

Tags: node.js, sqlite, typeorm

I am using the TypeOrm 0.2.24. I have a join table between (1) PopTaggerProfile (owner side) and (2) Tag

```
class PopTaggerProfile:
@manytomany((type) => Tag, (tag) => tag.id, { cascade: true })
@JoinTable()
selectedTags: Tag[];
```

```
class Tag:
 @manytomany((type) => PopTaggerProfile, (popTaggerProfile) => popTaggerProfile.id, { onDelete: "CASCADE", })
popTaggerProfiles: PopTaggerProfile[];
```

The issue:

I can add and save new data alright, and new relations between the two is stored into `pop_tagger_profile_selected_tags_tag` table, which as I can see is committed in the log and browse using database tool.

But when I start the app next time, all the data on this join table is dropped for some reason, and the table left blank as a new connection to the sqlite database is created. But data on PopTaggerProfile and Tag tables are not affected and they are preserved all right.

What did I do wrong? My connection setting:

```
 type: "sqlite",
 database: "database.sqlite",
 synchronize: true, 
 logging: true,
 entities: [Tag, TagRelation, PopTaggerProfile, ProjectProfile],
 subscribers: [TagRelationSubscriber]
```